# setStatusBarHidden magically fixes not working pushViewControllers, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to push two view controllers on the viewControllers stack, here's a simplified version of the code:

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:navigationController.viewControllers];

[viewControllers addObject:vc1];
[viewControllers addObject:vc2];

[navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
```

It works most of the time, but on some devices *sometimes* it does not. When it does not work the code literally does nothing (visually), no new views appear on the screen. Step by step debugging does not reveal anything unusual, the views are initialized properly and are indeed added on top of the viewControllers stack.

Changing the code to using `pushViewController` twice instead of `setViewControllers` did not fix it. However, I found the weirdest fix that works extremely well:

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];

[viewControllers addObject:vc1];
[viewControllers addObject:vc2];

[self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];

// The following two lines fix the issue
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                        withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO
                                        withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

This is a bad hack, especially considering setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation: [is deprecated since iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622949-setstatusbarhidden?language=objc).

What does `setStatusBarHidden:` do that might cause the viewControllers stack to appear properly?

Comment: Are you possibly calling this from a thread other than the main / UI thread? And... does your navigationController *already* have view controllers on its stack?

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for taking the time to think about it! It is on the main thread (confirmed with [NSThread isMainThread]). And navigationController has one viewController on its stack which is the current view.

Answer (score 0):

1. do you consider the afterdely effect?

   dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO
                                       withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
   });
2. alse: in viewcontroller or navigationcontroller use:

   -(BOOL)statusBarHidden
   {
   return YES;
   }

Comment: Thank you for an attempt, Liang Chen! This looks like another hack to me. I already have a hack that works but I don't understand _why_ it works. Can you explain why your solution would work?